# FullPage.js - Slider auto scrolling to the top section everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

So I have a simple 2 slider section using fullpage.js.

**Problem**: I want to add a scrollbar, which I have done using `autoScrolling` (because not only can you scroll by clicking the scrollbar but also with the roller on your mouse). **The problem is that the page jumps to the top section when the slider is auto moving.**

*For example if I am viewing the footer section (Anything below the slider) it will auto jump to the top section.*

Html

```
<div class="hero-box">
    <div id="slide-wrapper">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="slide">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(max-width: 620px)" srcset="img/hero-slider-mobile.jpg">
                    <source media="(min-width: 621)" srcset="img/hero-slider-tablet.jpg">
                    <img src="img/hero-slider-home.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:100%;">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(max-width: 620px)" srcset="img/slide-2-mobile.jpg">
                    <source media="(min-width: 621)" srcset="img/slide-2-tablet.jpg">
                    <img src="img/slide-2-home.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:100%;">
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<!-- Call the fullpage slider script on slide-wrapper id -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slide-wrapper').fullpage({
            css3: true,
            loopBottom: true,
            autoScrolling: false,
            afterRender: function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Additionally:** Also is it possible to make the slider arrows smaller? It is too big on the mobile screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fullpage.js option `fitToSection:false`